# Example of an amenable enveloping von-Neumann algebra

Tags: von-neumann-algebras, amenability

I am looking for an example of an infinite dimensional $C^{*}$-algebra whose second dual is amenable.  Can anyone supply a suggested reference?  Many thanks in advance.

**Edit:**  If this is inappropriate for overflow, please forgive my rudeness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a silly question.  Any subhomogeneous $C^{*}$-algebra will suffice.

Comment: It's neither rude nor silly to have an honest question. Actually it might be good to pretend that not all of us are experts (you won't have to pretend very hard), and flesh this out into more of a solution, possibly with some recollection of what the terms mean.

Comment: If you accept your own answer, it will no longer be bumped to the homepage by the robot

Comment: done, thanks!  just feel awkward accepting my own answer when its low quality